# Mathematical Theory (Static and Dynamics) for multiple charges in space:

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, charge, computational-physics, stability

Which treatable general theory or mathematical tool is best suited to deal with multiple electrical charges in 2D and 3D spaces in terms of static analysis and in equilibrium condition and also its dynamics showing paths independently of the number of particles?

Comment: This is too vague a question. Maxwell's equations, Lorentz formula, differential calculus? What specifically are you trying to understand?

Comment: Imagine that we are talking about an atomic model where we have N electrons (negative charges) orbiting around a nucleus containing N protons (positive charges). Electrodynamically how to deal with the problem of the trajectories of each electron?

Comment: Write down all equations of motion for all particles (net force is sum of forces due to all other particles) and integrate them numerically. The simplest case for proton+electron in retarded variant of the EM theory was analyzed by J. L. Synge, *On the electromagnetic two–body problem.*, Proc. Roy. Soc. A 177 118–39 (1940)

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1940.0114

Comment: Thank you for sharing the Synge's work. It is an interesting begin to my development. Do you imagine that from this work could be possible generalize to many charged bodies?

Comment: Yes, the generalization of the equations to $N$ particles  is obvious, however solving them becomes a very difficult task, best solved numerically using computer. It is similar to gravitational n-body problem, but even more difficult because of retardation.

Comment: Yes, it is a very difficult task to solve the N-body problem analitically. But can you suggest some theory

Comment: Yes, it is a very difficult task to solve the N-body problem analitically. But can you suggest some mathematical methods for investigation on the shape of stable regions with charged particles like the atom model (electrons orbiting the nucleous with prótons). I think that this way could be similar to atomic orbital determination.

Comment: Using Wave Functions in 3D Schrodinger equation we can find the shape of these orbitals, but my question there is other way to reach the same orbital-waveforms using only Coulombian attraction and repulsion.

Comment: I don't know, but it is unlikely that Coulombic forces alone in classical theory result in anything like orbitals, because size of quantum theoretical orbitals is around 1angstrom and there is no such scale in classical EM theory (there is no $h$, or in other words it is zero).

Comment: If other forces such as background EM noise are included in the model (stochastic electrodynamics, SED), things get more interesting, a localization similar to orbitals can be observed, but the results that I know are inconclusive about the SED model, there are problems with stability. See the paper by Cole D.C, Zou Y., https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0307154, and paper by Nieuwenhuizen T. M., Liska M. T. P, https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06856 .

Comment: For a short review of attempt to model hydrogen using SED, see also Maclay G. J., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07343.pdf .